# Create POST API to update order custom fields using increment ID

Tags: magento2, api, custom

I need to update order custom attributes from increment ID using a custom REST API. 
I receive this XML :

```
<order>
  <data>
    <incrementId>000000007</incrementId>
    <blNumber>test</blNumber>
    <sapDocNumber>test666</sapDocNumber>
    <invoiceNumber></invoiceNumber>
  </data>   
</order>
```

I already created webapi.xml file taking example from magento order native module. But I don't know how to process then. Any help ?

Comment: Hi let me know what exact order details want to update?

Comment: I need to update new order field "field1" and "field2"

Comment: let me know whether you would like to change from REST API?

Comment: Yes, I need to use REST API, i'm going to update question so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found after one difficult day.

First of all, we need to create etc/webapi.xml file in my module :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/order/updatecustom" method="POST">
        <service class="Ns\Module\Api\CustomInterface" method="updateOrderCustomAttributes" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

So, we have our URL and what method to call. 
Then, we need to create our custom interface : file Api/CustomInterface.php in my module directory :

```
<?php
namespace Ns\Module\Api;

/**
 * Interface CustomInterface
 * @package Ns\Module\Api
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.1.2
 */
interface CustomInterface
{
    /**
     * Update order custom attributes
     *
     * @param \Ns\Module\Api\Data\OrderCustomInterface $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function 
updateOrderCustomAttributes(\Ns\Module\Api\Data\OrderCustomInterface $data);
}
```

Then, our method need to know what data we want to get. To do that, new interface in file Api/Data/OrderCustomInterface.php :

```
<?php
namespace Ns\Module\Api\Data;

/**
 * Interface OrderCustomInterface
 * @package Ns\Module\Api\Data
 * @api
 */
interface OrderCustomInterface
{
    const INCREMENT_ID = 'incrementId';

    const SAP_DOC_NUMBER = 'sapDocNumber';

    const INVOICE_NUMBER = 'invoiceNumber';

    const BL_NUMBER = 'blNumber';


    /**
     * Get order increment Id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIncrementId();

    /**
     * Get order Sap Doc number
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSapDocNumber();

    /**
     * Get invoice number
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInvoiceNumber();

    /**
     * Get BL number
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlNumber();

    /**
     * Set increment ID
     *
     * @param string $incrementId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIncrementId($incrementId);

    /**
     * Set SAP doc number
     *
     * @param string $sapIncrementId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSapDocNumber($sapIncrementId);

    /**
     * Set Invoice number
     *
     * @param string $invoiceNumber
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setInvoiceNumber($invoiceNumber);

    /**
     * Set BL number
     *
     * @param string $blNumber
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBlNumber($blNumber);

}
```

We have our 2 interfaces. We need to override its. 
We need a etc/di.xml to do that :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <preference for="Ns\Module\Api\CustomInterface" type="Ns\Module\Model\Custom" />
    <preference for="Ns\Module\Api\Data\OrderCustomInterface" type="Ns\Module\Model\OrderCustom" />
</config>
```

And next, we create these files : 
Ns/Module/Model/OrderCustom.php to get our data :

```
<?php
namespace Ns\Module\Model;

use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory;

/**
 * Interface Custom
 * @package Ns\Module\Model
 */
class OrderCustom extends AbstractModel implements \Ns\Module\Api\Data\OrderCustomInterface
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory
     * @param AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $data
        );
    }


    /**
     * Get order increment Id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIncrementId()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::INCREMENT_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Get order Sap Doc number
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSapDocNumber()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::SAP_DOC_NUMBER);
    }

    /**
     * Get invoice number
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInvoiceNumber()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::INVOICE_NUMBER);
    }

    /**
     * Get BL number
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlNumber()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::BL_NUMBER);
    }

    /**
     * Set increment ID
     *
     * @param string $incrementId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIncrementId($incrementId)
    {
        $this->setData(self::INCREMENT_ID, $incrementId);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set SAP doc number
     *
     * @param string $sapIncrementId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSapDocNumber($sapIncrementId)
    {
        $this->setData(self::SAP_DOC_NUMBER, $sapIncrementId);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set Invoice number
     *
     * @param string $invoiceNumber
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setInvoiceNumber($invoiceNumber)
    {
        $this->setData(self::INVOICE_NUMBER, $invoiceNumber);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set BL number
     *
     * @param string $blNumber
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBlNumber($blNumber)
    {
        $this->setData(self::BL_NUMBER, $blNumber);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And file /Ns/Module/Model/Custom.php to process our data :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Ns\Module\Model;

use \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;

/**
 * Interface Custom
 * @package Ns\Module\Model
 */
class Custom implements \Ns\Module\Api\CustomInterface
{

    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    protected $logger;

    /** @var OrderInterface */
    protected $order;

    /** @var OrderRepository */
    protected $orderRepository;


    /**
     * Custom constructor.
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        OrderInterface $order,
        OrderRepository $orderRepository
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }


    /**
     * Update order custom attributes
     *
     * @param \Ns\Module\Api\Data\OrderCustomInterface $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function updateOrderCustomAttributes(\Ns\Module\Api\Data\OrderCustomInterface $data)
    {
        $order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($data->getData($data::INCREMENT_ID));

        // Update blNumber
        if($data->getData($data::BL_NUMBER) != '')
        {
            $order->setData('bl_number', $data->getData($data::BL_NUMBER));
        }
        // update sapDocNumber
        if($data->getData($data::SAP_DOC_NUMBER) != '')
        {
            $order->setData('sap_doc_number', $data->getData($data::SAP_DOC_NUMBER));
        }
        // update invoiceNumber
        if($data->getData($data::INVOICE_NUMBER) != '')
        {
            $order->setData('invoice_number', $data->getData($data::INVOICE_NUMBER));
        }

        try{
            $order->save();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
        return 'done';
    }
}
```

We can now call our custom API with URL : http://domain.ext/rest/V1/order/updatecustom
Don't forget to send xml in POST data.

With this method you can send JSON too ! Magento convert JSON and XML to an object according to orderCustomInterface class.

Comment: do you have example on passing the data using json ?

Comment: it's working fine to use XML in POST data.